# Loki - App center empty

Tags: software-installation, release-loki, appcenter

I've installed lok 0.4 today and the app center is empty except for installed applications. This is a known bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1615270

However, the suggested workaround in the link (i.e. "if you restart (or otherwise kill appcenter) the issue will correct itself") does not work. Still empty.

Any ideas for another workaround?

Comment: It looks like the issue now has corrected itself. It apparently took a couple of restarts though

Comment: This question was asked before the other one this is marked as a duplicate of

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and type:

`sudo apt update` (and put in your password when asked)

This updates the software repositories of elementary OS. Then reboot.

AppCenter will now have all the software available to Loki.