# AppCenter does not install anything anymore

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

I have just installed LOKI in two PCs and I am having the same issue with both.

On App Center I can see the apps list; however when I choose any of them, click Install and I can see the progress bar, but nothing more happens.

Please note that after install I managed to install sucessfully with App Center a few tools; However I disabled the Guest account and since then I can't install anything.
I tried to reboot several times and to enable again the Guest Account - however the problem persists.

Additional info: Default language is PT-pt, but this change was one of the firsts - after change language I managed to install a few tools.

Any suggestions?

TIA

Carlos

Comment: i have the same problem... i try to install some apps and app center do nothing! i try with the terminal the same nothing! terminal put this out E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing? how to solve this? i delete the kde for that? i cant understand realy

Comment: Update: I have installed loki again on both PCs (wiping all partions before).
This time I didn´t disabled the guest account, but after some time I already has the same issue in one of the PCs again!
And an additional info: On the PC with AppCenter issues if I chose UPDATES I have nothing there - on the other PC on UPDATES I have several apps (i.e. AppCenter, Calculator, etc.).

Comment: Can you check if you have any apps on the UPDATE tab, or is also empty?

Comment: i have the same issue : impossible to download any apps in a fresh Loky install. Do you have solutions ?
Thank you

Comment: As aswered in https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/loki-app-center-empty  did you try to update the repository?
sudo apt update 
Have the same issue today, and was able to solve it.

Comment: Related: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7533/no-software-is-shown-in-appcenter-except-what-is-installed

Comment: I have this same issue. I tried to uninstall appcenter and install ubuntu software-center, but I cannot even get that to work on Loki.

Comment: AppCenter offerings are supremely limited: Can't see any office applications, nothing under development, system, i.e., four categories with **zero** apps, four with **one** app. Where to go?

Comment: @ShaneG Loki is based in Ubuntu 16.04 and now applies gnome-software instead of old Ubuntu software-center

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, try to run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt update
```

After this everything works fine for me. I've downloaded some apps and updated OS.

Alternatively you can fix it by running

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
```